# MariaDB odd in its simple usage of Active Record in different Debian 9 servers and Rails apps

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mariadb

**In a pair of OVZ-6 servers and same Ruby on Rails application, the simple select post comments (one-to-many association)**

```
<%= @post.comments.each do |c| %>
<%= c.body %>
<% end %>
```

**are displaying the three existent comments but some full records at the end:**

```
Great solution for a big and old problem.
This is a problem that I have started to web design years ago.
Thanks for facilitating this css files, this really help us!

[#<Comment id: 2, body: "Great solution for a big and old problem.",
post_id: 2, created_at: "2018-01-11 10:28:08", updated_at: "2018-01-11
10:28:08">, #<Comment id: 3, body: "This is a problem that I have
started to web desig...", post_id: 2, created_at: "2018-01-11
10:28:08", updated_at: "2018-01-11 10:28:08">, #<Comment id: 4, body:
"Thanks for facilitating this css files, this reall...", post_id: 2,
created_at: "2018-01-11 13:02:33", updated_at: "2018-01-11 13:02:33">]
```

**If there aren't comments it's displaying: []**

**The configuration of both servers, one fresh and other upgrade from Debian-8 is:**

Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch), Linux 4.9.0-1-amd64, x86-64. 
Apache 2.4.25 (Debian). Mysql 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB, debian-linux-gnu (x86_64), readline 5.2. (status below) Phusion Passenger 5.1.12. RVM
1.29.3. Ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-linux]. Rails 5.1.4. mysql2 (0.4.10)

**The BBDD status is:**

```
`$ sudo service mysql status`
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.2.12 database server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; ven
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
+-migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-01-10 11:58:23 UTC; 1 day
Docs: man:mysqld(8)
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
Process: 481 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment
Process: 478 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, s
Process: 208 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recove
Process: 202 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _
Process: 190 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root
Main PID: 393 (mysqld)
Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
+-393 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

**The sql file is:**

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
CREATE TABLE ar_internal_metadata (
key varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
value varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
created_at datetime NOT NULL,
updated_at datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
INSERT INTO ar_internal_metadata (key, value, created_at, updated_at) VALUES
('environment', 'development', '2018-01-10 16:44:47', '2018-01-10 16:44:47');
CREATE TABLE comments (
id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
body varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
post_id bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
created_at datetime NOT NULL,
updated_at datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
CREATE TABLE posts (
id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
title varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
body text COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
created_at datetime NOT NULL,
updated_at datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
CREATE TABLE schema_migrations (
version varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
ALTER TABLE comments
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_2fd19c0db7 FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts (id);
```

**The schema.rb file is:**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180111151927) do
create_table "posts", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin" do |t|
t.string "title"
t.text "body"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
create_table "comments", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin" do |t|
t.string "body"
t.bigint "post_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
end
add_foreign_key "comments", "posts"
end
```

**Through the rails console the select Post.last.comments shows the comments well.**

**In other RoR apps built also using scaffolds, the show comments is producing the same error:**

```
Comments
congratulations!
[#<Comment id: 1, body: "congratulations!", post_id: 1, created_at:
"2018-01-11 17:13:26", updated_at: "2018-01-11 17:13:26">]
```

**What can be the problem?
How can we fix this error?
How do you recommend to proceed?
Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Change `<%= @post.comments.each do |c| %>` to `<% @post.comments.each do |c| %>` (remove the `=`).

Comment: Solved in all apps and servers! thank you very much!

Comment: glad I could help